# regex matching duplicates in a comma separated list

Tags: regex, pcre, semgrep

I'm trying to regex match any duplicate words (i.e. alphanumeric and can have dashes) in some yaml with a PCRE tool.

I have found [a *consecutive, duplicate* regex matcher](https://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html):

```bash
(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(,\1)+(?=,|$)
```

it will catch:

```
hello-world,hello-world,goodbye-world,goodbye-world
```

but not the `hello-world`s in

```
hello-world,goodbye-world,goodbye-world,hello-world
```

Could someone help me try to build a regex pattern for the second case (or both cases)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
(?<=,|^)([^,]+)(?=(?>,[^,]*)*,\1(?>,|$)),
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fdLTnS/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=^|,)`: Assert that we have `,` or start position before current position
- `([^,]+)`: Match 1+ of non-comma text and capture in group #1
- `(?=(?>,[^,]*)*,\1(?>,|$))`: Lookahead to assert presence of same value we captured in group #1 ahead of us
- `,`: Match `,`

Comment: oh interesting!  This is also a valid regex.  @anubhava thank you for your explanation! :-)

Comment: Just for my understanding are you looking to match only `hello-world` and not match `goodbye-world` using this regex?

Comment: the goal was to catch any duplicate.    the regex i originally had only captured consecutive duplicates which was not sufficient.

Comment: @torrho: Thanks for confirming and I was also thinking same. But then I don't understand how you've selected `(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?:,.*)?(,\1)(?=,|$)` as working answer which gives incorrect results i.e. showing only 1 match instead of 2.

Comment: @anubhava the tool I am working with, semgrep, seems to work with the answer provided for the time being.  I am still testing but I am beginning to think your original answer - sans the comma, might be _just_ a little more effective in what I am trying to do here.  

Should my testing change to your answer, i'll revise my "correct answer" selection.

Comment: @anubhava :-) I used your original regex as it has tested just a little bit better than the prior answer.  

Thank you Barmar for your answer as well.  They both work for the purpose that I am trying to do however i think anubhava answer has cleaner test results in my tool.  thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Put an optional `,.*` between the capture group and the back-reference.

```
(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?:,.*)?(,\1)(?=,|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/HGPUh4/2)

Comment: But wouldn't it miss `goodbye-world` as dupe?